# type error while trying to outer-merge two dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I've got two dfs, one from excel and another one, bigger one, from Vertica. The one from Vertica has some missing values in the column that i'm going to use as a key for merge (dispatch_number), but i've managed to convert its values to int64 type, so values in "dispatch_number" column in both dfs are int64.
However, when i try to perform outer merge with a following code:

```
merged = pd.merge(left = first_df, 
                  right = second_df, 
                  how = "outer", 
                  on = "dispatch_number", 
                  suffixes = ("first", "second"))
```

i get the following type error after a huge traceback:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NAType'
```

The traceback itself is as follows:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-56d9936b0f01> in <module>
      1 #теперь left-мерджим два наших датафрейма, слева ставим датафрейм из вертики, потому что он более объемный
      2 
----> 3 merged = pd.merge(left = avito_df, right = pochta, how = "left", on = "dispatch_number", suffixes = ("avito", "pochta"))
      4 merged.head()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
     87         validate=validate,
     88     )
---> 89     return op.get_result()
     90 
     91 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in get_result(self)
    666             self.left, self.right = self._indicator_pre_merge(self.left, self.right)
    667 
--> 668         join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer = self._get_join_info()
    669 
    670         llabels, rlabels = _items_overlap_with_suffix(

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in _get_join_info(self)
    882             )
    883         else:
--> 884             (left_indexer, right_indexer) = self._get_join_indexers()
    885 
    886             if self.right_index:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in _get_join_indexers(self)
    860     def _get_join_indexers(self):
    861         """ return the join indexers """
--> 862         return _get_join_indexers(
    863             self.left_join_keys, self.right_join_keys, sort=self.sort, how=self.how
    864         )

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in _get_join_indexers(left_keys, right_keys, sort, how, **kwargs)
   1326         for n in range(len(left_keys))
   1327     )
-> 1328     zipped = zip(*mapped)
   1329     llab, rlab, shape = [list(x) for x in zipped]
   1330 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in <genexpr>(.0)
   1323     # get left & right join labels and num. of levels at each location
   1324     mapped = (
-> 1325         _factorize_keys(left_keys[n], right_keys[n], sort=sort, how=how)
   1326         for n in range(len(left_keys))
   1327     )

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in _factorize_keys(lk, rk, sort, how)
   1955         #  and rk is datetime-dtype
   1956         klass = libhashtable.Int64Factorizer
-> 1957         lk = ensure_int64(np.asarray(lk))
   1958         rk = ensure_int64(np.asarray(rk))
   1959 

pandas/_libs/algos_common_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.algos.ensure_int64()
```

Comment: Hi, could you show how you dealt with NaN values in Vertica df?

Comment: Hi, it was done like this: `first_df["dispatch_number"] = first_df["dispatch_number"].convert_dtypes()
first_df["dispatch_number"] = pd.to_numeric(first_df["dispatch_number"], errors = "coerce")
first_df["dispatch_number"] = pd.to_numeric(first_df["dispatch_number"], errors = "coerce").convert_dtypes()`

Comment: @Laurent do you think i should probably do the drop na thing?

Comment: Indeed, but before resorting to dropping, you could first consider to use `fillna` method?

Comment: fill na did not help :(

Comment: Not sure what's happening here. Could you edit your question to add the output of  `first_df.head(5).to_dict()` and `second_df.head(5).to_dict()` ?